# Unable to dismiss UIViewController from UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an iOS application which at the root has a UITabBarController (which has three tabs).

In the first tab in viewDidAppear: I have the following to present RegisterViewController if the user has not yet registered:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
RegisterViewController *registerViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RegisterView"];
[registerViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
[self presentViewController:registerViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

When the user taps on a "Register" button in RegisterViewController it presents QuestionnaireViewController once the HTTP response has been received.

When the taps on a "Submit" button in QuestionnaireViewController I am able to dismiss this with:

```
[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

I then post a notification which RegisterViewController is listening for:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:UserHasCompletedQuestionnaireNotification object:nil];
```

Now, here is where my problem lies - When RegisterViewController hears the notification I try and dismiss it, however cannot.

I have tried various connotations of dismissing it such as:

```
[[self tabBarController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

which does nothing, and:

```
[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

which gives the following errors:

```
attempt to dismiss modal view controller whose view does not currently appear. self = <RegisterViewController: 0x8525ea0> modalViewController = <UINavigationController: 0x74545e0>
attempt to dismiss modal view controller whose view does not currently appear. self = <UITabBarController: 0x8320060> modalViewController = <RegisterViewController: 0x8525ea0>
```

Hopefully someone is going to be able to tell me I am doing something stupidly wrong here.

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

If you want to dismiss both controllers at the same time, you can eliminate the notification, and do this (from QuestionnaireViewController):

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

If I understand your structure correctly, self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController should be the controller in the first tab that presented RegisterViewController. Dismissing it also dismisses anything that it presented.

Comment: I have already tried that, and unfortunately it does not do anything.

Comment: If you log self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController, what does it give you?

Comment: self.presentingViewController = UITabBarController,
self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController = null

Comment: My sincere apologies rdelmar, I misread your original answer.  I have called presentingViewController.presentingViewController within QuestionnaireViewController and it works - thank you very much.

Comment: I am still confused however, as to why my original design does not work.

Comment: @Nick, I'm not sure why it didn't work either. It could be that you were trying to do the second dismiss before the first dismiss animation was complete.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: [self dismissViewController:YES completion:nil]; is used to dismiss the view controller that the receiver presents, so in this case won't work, as RegisterViewController is the view controller I wish to dismiss.